# Equating numbers of the same type?

Tags: recursion, tree, prolog

I have four different node types.

```
leaf(Int)
node1(Leaf, Node1)
node2(Leaf, Node1, Node2)
node3(Leaf, Node1, Node2, Node3)
```

I'm looking to write a function, using mainly pattern matching, to check if we have the number of `n` nodes in a tree. For example, I run the function counter(Tree, c(1, 2, 1, 3)) would return true iff `Tree` has `one leaf`, `two single nodes`, `one double nodes`, and `three triple nodes`.

---

I'm trying to solve the problem in two different ways, but neither of them seem to be working.

The first method, is to use a helper function, where the helper function would go through `Tree` and counter the number of each type of node. Then simply run `is` on it.

The second method is to count down from tuple we check as soon we enter. Where we go from `c(N1, N2, N3, N4)` to `c(N1, N2 - 1, N3, N4)` if we hit a node with a single child.

---

The issue with the first method is, I'm trying to avoid using the unification function `=`, so any idea how I can go lower down the tree while updating the tuple in the helper function.

The issue with the second is that there is no way for me to know when it ends, as it could reach a leaf but I wouldn't be able to reach the other side of the tree to continue and relay that the tuple changed.

I figure the best way to get around this is the first one. Using a helper function and then trying to find the number of nodes in the tree by myself. I can believe that there are other methods to solve this, but this seems to be the most efficient.

---

Here's what my code for the first method looks like:

```
countNodes(leaf(_), c(N1, N2, N3, N4)) :-
    c(N0 + 1, N1, N2, N3).
countNodes(node1(_, Node), c(N1, N2, N3, N4)) :- 
    countNodes(Node, c(N1, N2 + 1, N3, N4)).
countNodes(node2(_, Node1, Node2), c(N1, N2, N3, N4)) :-
    countNodes(Node1, c(N1, N2, N3 + 1, N4)),
    countNodes(Node2, c(N1, N2, N3 + 1, N4)).
```

And at that point it basically falls apart. I'm trying to add the count node twice, which means the further in we go, the worse it will get. Any ideas on how to rewrite it and avoid double counting when there are two or three children from a node?

Thank you, any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your code, I propose the following (caution: not tested)

```
countNodes(leaf(_), c(1, 0, 0, 0)).

countNodes(node1(_, Node), c(N1, N2, N3, N4)) :- 
    countNodes(Node, c(N1, N2a, N3, N4)),
    N2 is N2a+1.

countNodes(node2(_, Node1, Node2), c(N1, N2, N3, N4)) :-
    countNodes(Node1, c(N1a, N2a, N3a, N4a)),
    countNodes(Node2, c(N1b, N2b, N3b, N4b)),
    N1 is N1a+N1b,
    N2 is N2a+N2b,
    N3 is N3a+N3b+1,
    N4 is N4a+N4b.

countNodes(node3(_, Node1, Node2, Node3), c(N1, N2, N3, N4)) :-
    countNodes(Node1, c(N1a, N2a, N3a, N4a)),
    countNodes(Node2, c(N1b, N2b, N3b, N4b)),
    countNodes(Node3, c(N1c, N2c, N3c, N4c)),
    N1 is N1a+N1b+N1c,
    N2 is N2a+N2b+N2c,
    N3 is N3a+N3b+N3c,
    N4 is N4a+N4b+N4c+1.
```

As you can see, the case `leaf` is very simple: you only have to set the values 1, 0, 0 and 0.

For the other cases, you have to call `countNodes` recursively over subnodes. Next you can add the found values (using `is`) and adding `+1` for the local node.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to test it and report back :)